# Exclude empty models in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a webApp that has posts and categories. Each category can have many posts and one post only belongs to one category.

In the index view I want to show the posts ordered by categories, so my view is:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  #shows category name
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <% if post.category_id == category.id.to_s %>
      #shows summary of post fields in a row; such as title, date, etc
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that it also shows the empty categories, i.e. categories without posts.

How could I filter this efficiently and avoid empty categories of been displayed? This is my controller method:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

An additional issue that bothers me is that my view will loop through all categories and posts everytime to show the rows, which could end slowing the app if the number of posts is large. Any idea of how to do this in a more efficient way?

**UPDATE:**

Currently implemented solution, including the filter of posts older than 3 days (more info in the comments). In the controller:

```
 def index
@categories = Category.includes(:posts).select{|c| c.posts.where(['created_at > ?', 3.days.ago]).count > 0} 
end
```

This only loads categories containing posts created in last 3 days. Note that older than 3 days posts still are loaded if the category has some newer than 3 days.

In the view, I filter those posts older than 3 days that I don't want to show.

```
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
  # do  category stuff
     <% category.posts.where(['created_at > ?', 3.days.ago]).each do |post| %>
     # do post stuff
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

I am pretty sure has to be a better way of doing it, but at least this way the db is called only once.

Comment: show your `post.rb` and `category.rb`, if you have set up the association between the two models, `@posts = Post.all` is unnecessary since you will be accessing `posts` via `category.posts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you setup the association on your models correctly you don't need to call posts and categories separately, you're creating an extra DB call unnecessarily as you can include the posts on categories. Similarly you can also exclude categories without posts from the get go.

```
  def index
    @categories = Category.includes(:posts).select{|c| c.posts.count > 0}
  end
```

So what we're doing here, is including the posts so that we don't have to make extra db calls as we iterate over the posts.  Secondly we are using select with a block to give a custom condition to match only categories with posts by iterating over the initial scope.   A caveat here is that select will return an array of objects instead of an active record association (though using '.all' does this anyway).

On your page you would then iterate this array like:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
      # do  category stuff
   <% category.posts.each do |post| %>
      # do post stuff
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Many thanks, this clarifies a lot. Although not included in my original question, I also filter to show only posts created in the last 3 days, so my controller actually was `@posts= post.where(['created_at > ?', 3.days.ago]).all`

I guess this can be done within your solution as well; where would you include that condition? In the controller or in the view?

I'm not sure how to include this directly in the controller.

I assume in the view this would work `category.posts.where(['created_at > ?', 3.days.ago]).each do |post|`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  The best place to do this would be in your controller.  Category.includes(:posts).where(['created_at > ?', 3.days.ago]).select{|c| c.posts.count > 0}

Comment: This seems to work to filter categories older than 3 days; but the intention is to filter posts older than 3 days. I'm able to do that in the view, but I wanted to do it in the controller to avoid loading all the posts to show only the ones created during last 3 days.